# Do we have cast sdk for windows?

Tags: google-cast

Do we have cast sdk for windows?

Looking at the cast API reference it seems we have sender API for Andriod and Ios  only.

I am looking for ways to cast content from my windows laptop other than from chrome.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a Windows SDK at this time.  However, Leon Nicholls has written a Java app that will cast from Windows.  https://github.com/entertailion/Fling

This does require a whitelisted Chromecast device.  https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting

Answer (score 0):

There is no such official library or support outside of Chrome browser. The mentioned [library](http://github.com/entertailion/Fling) is not an official library and is not supported by Google, hence can stop working upon any future updates.

Comment: Really??? The question asks if there is a windows SDK for and that is exactly what I have answered, so after more than 2 years, you claim that is not an answer???

Comment: No need to get upset. I don't think the time of answering is relevant in any way. I looked up this question and got here as a reader, and as such I rated the answer. And I don't see how my claim is false. IMO this answer should have been a comment.

Comment: The question is clear: "is there a cast sdk for windows?", so the answer is clear too: "no, there is no such sdk for windows", so what part of it you don't understand as an answer??

Comment: In your answer, you referred to a previous answer, made by @Doug Lamb. Which means, you did read the answer before you added yours. His answer starts with the words "There is not a Windows SDK at this time."
In addition, you quote the title of the question, when the more specific request was "I am looking for ways to cast content from my windows laptop other than from chrome.". This calls for ways which are not necessarily an official SDK and that is what he got. Your answer only added the fact that this library is not supported by google, which, IMO, belongs in a comment.